# How to match following combination of letters

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I want to match as and rs in any order.

Valid:

```
r
s
a
rs
sr
as
sa
```

Invalid:

```
ra - ar
asr - ars - sra - sar - rsa - ras
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a character class based regex like below.

```
\b(?:[ra]s|s[ar]|[ars])\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dX0kI5/3)

Comment: Sry I edited the main question I forgot that It should also be valid to match the following  characters a and r and s only if they are alone.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(?!(.)\1)(?:[rs]{1,2}|[as]{1,2})\b
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rO0yD8/3

Comment: Sry I edited the main question I forgot that It should also be valid to match the following  characters a and r and s only if they are alone.